# Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:provider(?)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am updating compose libraries:

```
compose = "1.5.4"
composeBom = "2023.10.01"
```

List of Libraries:

```
compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
compose-runtime = { group = "androidx.compose.runtime", name = "runtime" }
compose-foundation = { group = "androidx.compose.foundation", name = "foundation" }
compose-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
compose-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
compose-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
```

When I start building I get such error:

[image]

Other libraries which can affect on it:

```
gradle = "8.1.3"
kotlin = "1.9.20"
```

Helpful screen on build output:

[image]

Comment: Fixed problem:
actual: 
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.compose
    }

Solution:
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.compose.get()
    }